# Surgical strikes by India

Tags: india, pakistan, kashmir

Surgical strikes against Pakistani terrorists have been happening for a long time by India. What used to be clandestine operations are now publicised by the present government. What brought about this change?

Answer (score 2):

[This article](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2019/feb/26/pakistan-india-jets-breached-ceasefire-line-kashmir-bomb) lays out the reason it's making headlines:

> While exchanges of artillery and light weapons over the line are very common, intentional incursions by aircraft have not been publicly acknowledged since the two countries fought a war in 1971.